# PHP: Can you put a DateTime object in a while loop?

Tags: php, datetime

I saw this code on a [forum](http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/php-34/dateinterval-dateperiod-alternative-php-5-2x-726121.html):

```
 $begin = new DateTime( $start_date );
    $end = new DateTime(date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+1 day", strtotime($end_date))));
    while($begin < $end) {
        $period[] = $begin->format('Y-m-d');
        $begin->modify('+1 day');
    }
```

I want to do exactly what the OP was asking i.e. create a date interval of 1 day without using `DateInterval` class as I am not using PHP 5.3 (I'm using 5.2)

However when I try to use the $period array I get an error:

**Undefined variable: period**

This is my code:

```
    $start = new DateTime("09-09-2011");
    $end   = new DateTime("24-09-2011");

         while($start < $end) {

        $period[] = $start->format('Y-m-d');
        $start->modify('+1 day');

        }

print_r($period) //error - undefined variable
```

Why does it not work - is it to do with putting a datetime object in a while loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so define it easily

```
$period = array();
```

however, this will never go to that while loop = this code is not useful

Comment: yes - this was actually the right answer - but the code above works fine, it was just that my start date and end date were the same in the actual code but I modifies it for the post above.

Answer (score 1):

`$period` is defined in your `while()` loop. If the loop never runs (ie, if `$start < $end` never evaluates to `true`) the variable is never defined.

You can correct this by explicitly defining the variable before the `while()` loop:

```
$period = array();
while($start < $end) {
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare DateTime objects directly unless you're using PHP 5.2.2 or newer.  If you're using an older version then your while condition will never evaluate to true and your loop will never run.  As a result, your period array will never be created.

You'll probably have to extract the values of the dates from the datetime objects and compare them some other way.

Failing that, you could upgrade to a newer version of PHP.

Comment: The code above works - you can compare datetime objects in this way.

Comment: From the documentation: As of PHP 5.2.2, DateTime objects can be compared using comparison operators. In other words, prior to 5.2.2, you can't.

Comment: Ah ok - I am on 5.2.6 - phew!